# Requirement that determinant be zero for characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

In one book I'm reading that

> [...]
>   $\newenvironment{rcases}
>   {\left.\begin{aligned}}
>   {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}$
>
> $\begin{rcases}
>   (a_{11}-\lambda)x_1+a_{12}x_2=0, \\
>   a_{21}x_1+(a_{22}-\lambda)x_2=0
> \end{rcases}$
>
> for some scalar $\lambda$. Since the equations for $x_1, x_2$ comprise a linear homogeneous system, and since $x_1^2+x_2^2\ne 0$, an eigenvalue $\lambda$ must be such that the determinant of the system vanishes: thus
>
> $$\lambda^2 - (a_{11}+a_{22})\lambda+a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=0$$

I don't see how the fact that  $x_1^2+x_2^2\ne 0$ implies the necessity for the determinant to be equal zero. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Remember that a (square) linear homogeneous system has a unique solution (i.e. $\vec x = \vec 0$ is the only solution to $A \vec x = \vec 0$) if and only if $A$ has a non-zero determinant.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I certainly know that, but this is irrelevant to my question I think.

Comment: Typos: you (or the book) are missing an $x_2$ in the first equation and an $x_1$ in the second.

Comment: Writing $x_1^2 + x_2^2 \neq 0$ instead of $(x_1, x_2) \neq (0, 0)$ here is a killer-whale-sized red herring.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I agree, this creates unnecessary confusion and waste of time. It may, however, also prompt one to become a bit more contemplative and deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_1^2 + x_2^2 \neq 0$ is just another way of saying that the vector $(x_1, x_2)$ is not $(0,0)$. So, $(A -\lambda I) x = 0$ has a nontrivial solution. Thus, $A - \lambda I$ is singular, that is, its determinant equals zero.